# Proving that a limit of a function does not exist

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
-1,  & \text{if $x<0$} \\[2ex]
0, & \text{if $x = 0$} \\[2ex]
1, & \text{if $x>0$} 
\end{cases}$

How do I prove that the limit $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)$ doesn't exist using epsilon-delta definition?

I don't know how to proceed from 
$|f(x) - L| <\epsilon$, since I don't know how to define what $f(x)$ is when $x$ is getting close to $0$

Comment: A very brief sketch of the proof would be: "It cannot have a limit $L\ge 0$, because $f(x)=-1$ arbitrarily close to $0$, and so $|f(x)-L|\ge 1$ arbitarily close to $0$. On the other hand, it can't have a limit $L<0$ either, because $f(x)=1$ arbitrarily close to $0$..." Can you express that reasoning in epsilon-delta form?

Answer (score 1):

Show $\lim_{x \to o^+} f(x) = 1, \lim_{x \to 0^-} f(x)=-1$.

Comment: This actually will com straight from the definition and taking $\delta = \epsilon$.